# Trigger between linked servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, linked-server

I have two SQL Server 2008 machines, `SQLSERVER1` and `SQLSERVER2` (soo original)

In `SQLSERVER2`, I do:

```
[SQLSERVER1].[DATABASE].[DBO].StoreProcedure1
```

All works well.

But if I put into a trigger, I receive this error

> *OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "[SQLSERVER1]" returned message
>   "No transaction is active.".
>
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure StoreProcedure1, Line 57
>
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for 
>   linked server "[SQLSERVER1]" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.*

Comment: What does this trigger do?

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure that your linked servers allow RPC in and out.

Server Objects-> Linked Servers-> Right-click the server and choose Properties -> Server Options

RPC should be "True" and RPC Out should be "True"

You should also ensure that you've enabled DTC Network Access on the servers so that it use distributed transactions.